# Drawing in screen with finger in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, touches

I am following this excellent small tutorial about drawing on screen in the layer of a UIView (subclass). 
http://spritebandits.wordpress.com/
It just works.

There is just one thing. I placed this view as subview of a UITableViewCell which, naturally, is displayed as part of a UITableView.
I guess I would have the same issue when I would place it within an UIScrollView. (UITableView inherits from UIScrollView anyway)

Touches are triggered by my painting view as long as their related movement is horizontal. As soon as I move the finger kinda vertical, even partly, then the UITableView takes over and scrolls the table.

Is there any proper way of stopping the Table to taike control of the touches while the touch is actually within my view?

If it is of importance: I am using storyboard. The cell is a prototype cell with its own subclass of UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 1):

I've implemented this using the same class "Canvas" you're saying and also inside a UITableViewCell. But I didn't use the entire cell for drawing, only a UIView inside of the UITableView as a subview.

I reached the whole user experience by activating and deactivating the UITableView scrolling when that UIView (subview of the cell where I allow the drawing) fires touchesBegan or touchesEnded. So when they touch/move inside the UIView, they're drawing. When it's outside, they're scrolling. So they can't scroll on the UIView because they will be drawing.

The problem in your case is that since the whole cell is the view for drawing, the user cannot scroll in this concrete cell because it's the drawing one.

Hope this will help.

Comment: My Canvas subview is only part of that cell as well. There are other lables and buttons in the cell. There will be plenty of space on all sides of the Canvas view for the user to drag for scrolling the table. And I tried the same trick. I traced when touchesBegan is fired. It is fired only when the user moves sideways. I won't notice any movement with up-down-components. Did you use a trick to come around that?

Comment: Uhm.. one thing, if you tap on the Canvas and then move the finger up & down it's scrolling or drawing? (try it slowly, first the tap on the Canvas, and then the swipe up or down a bit)

Comment: I just tried it. In touchesBegan I first climb up the superview chain until I find a UITableView and set scrollEnabled to NO. The same in touchesEnded: with YES. So, when the user starts drawing vertically it works fine. The user can change the direction and continues drawing. And when the user starts drawing but waits a moment after touching before actually moving the finger, then it works fine too. But when the user starts horzontal or diagonal or so then the table scrolls.

Comment: Then I think this is because touchesBegan is not fired since the first gesture is not recognized as a tap, is directly a swipe. Maybe you could try to capture those gestures at the UITableView and send that actions to the Canvas methods. I've not tried that, but it's an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I dont have an answer for that. But there is essentially a work around.

You could get the user in to a drawing mode, where the scrolling for a UItableviewcell is disabled and then

once the user is done with drawing, you could enable scrolling again.

Inclusion of a button anywhere on the screen would help you switch modes.

Comment: Thanks. Technically that could work. But is this a good user experience? Anyway. I could try to disable the scrolling while the user actually draws something. But that will not work when the user starts drawing in a vertical direction.